# How to receive the InkCanvas.StrokeCollected event in the view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inkcanvas

In using MVVM pattern, I have a custom inkcanvas with:

```
   protected override void OnStrokeCollected(InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomStroke newStroke = new CustomStroke(e.Stroke.StylusPoints, e.Stroke.DrawingAttributes);
        this.Strokes.Remove(e.Stroke);
        this.Strokes.Add(newStroke);
        InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs eNew = new InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs(newStroke);

        // Raises the System.Windows.Controls.InkCanvas.StrokeCollected event.
        base.OnStrokeCollected(eNew);
    }
```

How do I get the view model to receive the InkCanvas.StrokeCollected event?

I can not bind the XAML to the strokes as the StrokeCollection.CollectionChanged event will be called three times by the custom inkcanvas.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    public Window3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm=new ViewModel();
        this.DataContext = vm;
        canvas.StrokeCollected += vm.OnStrokeCollected;
    }
```

> ViewModel

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public void OnStrokeCollected(object sender, InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs e)
    { 

    }
}
```

> Edit

if you want to do it without codebehind see the article [EventTrigger](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2010/11/using-eventtrigger-in-xaml-for-mvvm-no.html)

Comment: Use EventTrigger if you want no code behind I added a link in answer

Answer (score 1):

You simply bind it via XAML as you already did, which is the correct way to do it.

That you get 3 events, doesn't matter. Just handle the one you need.

For example, if you are only interested in the `StrokeCollectedEvent`, then just do

```
protected override void OnStrokeCollected(InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.RoutedEvent != InkCanvas.StrokeCollectedEvent) 
         return;

     // handle the event
}
```

For a full list of Events, consult the "[Fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas_fields(v=vs.110).aspx)" Section of InkCanvas MSDN documentation. The fields ending with "Event" are RoutedEvent constants, which are passed in the `InkCanvasStrokeCollectedEventArgs`.

Comment: I would like to handle the event back in the view model. How would I get the view model to receive this event from the custom ink control?